# Mule4.xx Applying Offline Custom Policies

Tags: mule4, anypoint-platform

Has somebody managed to deploy a custom policy via offline [Applying Offline Custom Policies](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/offline-policy-task)

Any additional tricks besides the documentation mentioned  in the link above?

We want to apply mule4 custom policy without going through the any point platform but rather from the manual deploy on mule runtime as described in the document which states "If you do not want to use the policy template from... "

Comment: Did you had any problems trying the method described in the documentation link you mentioned?

Comment: No problem but the deployment on the mule 4  manually . Any document on how to deploy the custom policy manually